# SharePoint Online Provider hosted app upgrade error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have a provider hosted app with `AppInstalled`, `AppUninstalling` and `AppUpgraded` event receivers. Remote web for this app is hosted on Azure VM. App is available to all site collection through App Catalog site. I installed this app on one of my site collection. While testing the app upgrade feature, I encountered following error:

> The content database on the server is temporarily unavailable. Details: 0x80070002 There is no Web named "/_Copy.

I retried multiple times but no luck. I also tried on different site collections but I get the same error.

Furthermore, I observed that it is happening only with 'AppUpgraded' event receiver added. Upgrade works when I remove this event receiver.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. I tried to update an app 2hrs ago and I get the same message :(
I'm hoping this is a general issue at the side of Microsoft...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is no longer happening. Microsoft has been deploying fixes for SharePoint online and upgrade issue was one of them. To check fixes status go to this page -- [portal.office.com/ServiceStatus/ServiceStatus.aspx](http://portal.office.com/ServiceStatus/ServiceStatus.aspx)